# Can't push notification to APNS to update my pass in Apple Wallet

Tags: php, ios, passbook, wallet

I'm trying to push notification to APNS to update my pass in Apple Wallet app. According to [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW1), we only need to send the pass type identifier and the push token to APNs. Then they will take care of the rest.

```
$apnsHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
    $apnsPort = 2195;
    $apnsCert = base_path('app/config/passbook/certificates.pem');
    $payload = ['aps' => []];
    $payload = json_encode($payload);

    $streamContext = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'xxxxxx');

    $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

    if(!$apns) {
        Logger::logError(1, "Passbook push notification error", ['serial_number' => $serialNumber, 'pass_type_id' => $passIdentify]);
        return "Failed to connect (stream_socket_client): $error $errorString";
    } else {
        foreach($push_tokens as $idx => $push_token) {
            $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $push_token) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

            fwrite($apns, $msg);
        }
    }
    @socket_close($apns);
    fclose($apns);
```

There is no error returned but it seem doesn't work. What do I do wrong? Please help.

Comment: Are you sure it is not returning errors? As I see it, you are only writing to the socket and not reading. You are trying to send a notification to an app that is in production. Did you manage to send notifications to the app while in development using the sandbox gateway? Also, there might be some similar questions that could help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865331/stream-socket-client-unable-to-connect-to-ssl-gateway-sandbox-push-apple-co

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain clearly. I'm trying to push notification to APNS to update my pass in Apple Wallet app. According to [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW1), we only need to send the pass type identifier and the push token to APNs. Then they will take care of the rest.

Comment: What certificate are you using?

Comment: Also have you implemented all 5 end points of the web service.  If you pull down on the back of your pass, does it refresh?

Comment: @PassKit The certificate I'm using, is the one that I used to sign on creating pass (successfully). I used this command to export the .pem certificate  
`$ openssl pkcs12 -in WenderCastPush.p12 -out WenderCastPush.pem -nodes -clcerts`

Comment: If you pull down on the back of your pass, does it update?

Comment: @PassKit I also implemented all 5 end points of the web service (all work well). I noted that after the registration success, the device immediately send a request to my server to get the list of the serial numbers for passes associated with the device then get the latest version of the passes. All this process is successful, but when I try to push notification to APNS there is nothing happen.

Comment: If you pull down on the back of your pass, does it update? << Yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126149/discussion-between-hoang-trung-and-passkit).

Comment: Any one solve this problem? I have a same case. Push received but passbook not updated automatically. Pull to refresh is working.

Comment: @Michael I just added the code is currently working on my project, try it.

Comment: @HoangTrung thanks - i got this working. I'm now stuck on some of the server code to GET the serial & last modified, and then send the updated .pkpass file in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code working on my project

```
    $errors = [];
    $apnsHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
    $apnsPort = 2195;
    $apnsCert = base_path('app/config/passbook/certificates.pem');
    $payload = ['aps' => []];
    $payload = json_encode($payload);

    $streamContext = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'xxxxxxxxx');

    $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
    stream_set_blocking ($apns, 0);

    if( ! $apns) {
        return "Failed to connect (stream_socket_client): $error $errorString";
    } else {
        foreach($push_tokens as $idx => $push_token) {
            $msg = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $push_token)) . chr(0) . chr(mb_strlen($payload)) . $payload;

            $success = fwrite($apns, $msg);
            if ($success === strlen($msg)) { // log success
                Logger::logPassbook('Push success', ['push_token' => $push_token]);
            } else {
                Logger::logPassbook('Push failed', ['push_token' => $push_token]);
            }
        }
    }

    @socket_close($apns);
    fclose($apns);

    return $errors;
```

Comment: What should we write in ['aps' => []] in Payload string? I don't have any information about it. Could you please your sample Payload string here.

Comment: Binary protocol is no longer supported for the Apple Push Notification service. Please check the link: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=11042019a